Why is this string list/vector not getting updated?
I have a simple program where there is a vector of strings. Pressing one button adds items to this vector. Pressing another button should print out current contents of this vector. My code is a follows:
use fltk::{app, button::Button, prelude::*, window::Window};

fn main() {
    let app = app::App::default();
    let mut wind = Window::new(100, 100, 400, 300, "File Manager");

    let mut filenamelist: Vec::<String> = vec![];

    // Create buttons
    let mut add_item_btn = Button::new(50, 50, 100, 40, "Select File");
    let mut show_list_btn = Button::new(50, 120, 100, 40, "Show List");
    let mut exit_btn = Button::new(50, 190, 100, 40, "Exit");

    // Button callbacks
    {
        let mut filenamelist = filenamelist.clone();
        add_item_btn.set_callback(move |_| {
                filenamelist.push("ITEM_TO_BE_ADDED".to_string());
                println!("\nList in add_item_btn callback fn:");
                for f in filenamelist.iter() {  // THIS SHOWS ITEM IS ADDED TO THE VECTOR; 
                    println!("{}", f);
                }
            } );
    }

    {
        let filenamelist = filenamelist.clone();
        show_list_btn.set_callback(move |_| {
            println!("\nList in show_list_btn callback fn:");
            for f in filenamelist.iter() {      // THIS ALWAYS SHOWS EMPTY VECTOR; 
                println!("{}", f);
            }
        });
    }

    exit_btn.set_callback(|_| {
        app::quit();
    });

    wind.end();
    wind.show();
    app.run().unwrap();
}

I build and run the application in Linux with command cargo run. It builds with no errors. There is one warning:
let mut filenamelist  
    help: remove this `mut` 
note:    `#[warn(unused_mut)]` on by default

However, as the applicaton runs, as mentioned in comments in code above, the item gets added to the list in add_item_btn.set_callback function, but show_list_btn.set_callback function always shows an empty list.
Where is the error and how can it be solved?

Because you are adding your items to a cloned list, not the one one belonging to your form

If I add items to self.fileNameList , I get: error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of method

Please show [mcve] with this original error, it is more relevant than the incorrect attempt to work around it.

It is part of a larger application, which will be too much code to post here. Any comments or suggestions on code above will be very much appreciated.

Please read the linked article on how to produce a Minimal Reproducible Example. If it's too much code that means it is not a MRE, and therefore cannot be posted here.

This is still an incorrect workaround and not the original error. Plus, it's not strictly minimal - one doesn't have to use fltk to call these callbacks, they can be just called in the main directly, and the error is expected to be the same.

Following code works:
use fltk::{app, button::Button, prelude::*, window::Window};
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;   

fn showlist(flist: &Rc<RefCell<Vec<String>>>){
    for f in flist.borrow().iter(){
        println!("item: {}", f);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let app = app::App::default();
    let mut wind = Window::new(100, 100, 200, 300, "File Manager");

let filenamelist: Rc<RefCell<Vec<String>>> = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Vec::<String>::new()));

// Create buttons
let mut select_file_btn = Button::new(50, 50, 100, 40, "Select File");
let mut show_list_btn = Button::new(50, 120, 100, 40, "Show List");
let mut exit_btn = Button::new(50, 190, 100, 40, "Exit");

let filenamelist_cl1 = filenamelist.clone();
select_file_btn.set_callback(move |_| {  
                println!("\nList in select_file_btn callback fn:"); 
                filenamelist_cl1.borrow_mut().push("ITEM ADDED".to_string());
                showlist(&filenamelist_cl1); 
            } );
let filenamelist_cl2 = filenamelist.clone();
show_list_btn.set_callback(move |_| {
            println!("\nList in show_list_btn callback fn:");
            showlist(&filenamelist_cl2); 
        });
exit_btn.set_callback(move|_| {
        println!("\nList before quitting:"); 
        showlist(&filenamelist); 
        app::quit();
});

wind.end();
wind.show();
app.run().unwrap();

}
Rc and RefCell are needed for proper function of code.

Correction - there's no threading here, otherwise you'd be forced to use Arc and Mutex instead of Rc and RefCell.

I have corrected the comment in my answer above. What exactly are Rc and RefCell needed for?
